# How to use Text.Parsec in GHC-8.2.2 and Cabal-2.0.0.1

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, parsec

As I know `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec` is replaced by `Text.Parsec`

Here, it is my environment

```
4.9.73-1-MANJARO

The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2

cabal-install version 2.0.0.1
compiled using version 2.0.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

The following source code is my `main.hs`

```
module Main where
import System.Environment
import Text.Parsec

main :: IO ()
main = do
     args <- getArgs
     putStrLn (readExpr (args !! 0))
```

and then I compile it

```
$ ghc -package parsec -o main main.hs
```

It occurs the following error messages

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, main.o )

main.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Parsec’
    There are files missing in the ‘parsec-3.1.11’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Text.Parsec
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
rm: cannot remove '*.hi': No such file or directory
./run.sh: line 11: ./TestProj: No such file or directory
```

I make sure I have installed `parsec`. So I want to ask any mistake I've done?

```
$ cabal install parsec
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
parsec-3.1.11
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

Comment: What happens if you leave off `-package parsec`? So just run `ghc -o main main.hs`. [`-package`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#ghc-flag--package%20%E2%9F%A8pkg%E2%9F%A9) may not be doing what you think it is.

Comment: the result is same.

Comment: Are we to understand the `rm:` and `./run.sh` lines of the error are produced by ghc?

Comment: What happens when you `ghc-pkg check` as the error instructs?

Comment: Dear Thomas, I'm so sorry the message let you unclear. The `rm` and `./run.sh` doesn't provide by ghc. `run.sh` just my script to help compile and excute

Comment: 'ghc-pkg check` provide a lot of warning message such as below

`Warning: haddock-interfaces: /usr/share/doc/pandoc/html/pandoc.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file`
`Warning: haddock-html: /usr/share/doc/pandoc/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory`
`Warning: haddock-interfaces: /usr/share/doc/haskell-xml/html/xml.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file`
`Warning: haddock-html: /usr/share/doc/haskell-xml/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory`
`Warning: haddock-interfaces: /usr/share/doc/haskell-texmath/html/texmath.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manjaro might have inherited from Arch's issues with Haskell.

#### What is going on

Arch installs dynamic libraries, but `ghc` links statically by default. This is also what the error message "There are files missing in the ... package", indicating that the package exists but does not contain what `ghc` is looking for.

If I try compiling with the `-v` verbose flag on, the error message expands to:

```
ghc -v main.hs

(...)
Locations searched:
  Text/Parsec.hs
  Text/Parsec.lhs
  Text/Parsec.hsig
  Text/Parsec.lhsig
  /usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/site-local/parsec-3.1.11/Text/Parsec.hi
(...)
```

In particular, look into the last reported location, which may be different on your system; if my guess is correct, `ghc` is looking for a static interface file `.hi` as the message indicates but there is only a dynamic one `.dyn_hi`.

#### Fix

Compile with the `-dynamic` flag.

```
 ghc -dynamic main.hs
```

And if that works read this to fix the setup:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell

You will have to choose between static and dynamic linking; I don't actually understand the trade-off here.